# Google Maps vs Mapquest

Tags: google-maps, curl, mapquest

I figure I'd drop this question here.

I wrote a curl script that gets the longitude and latitude for an address using the google maps API.

Works great!

The problem I have is that when I check the coordinates that my script generated.... on Google Maps and Mapquest the maps show different locations on the same coordinates.

In this case the coordinates are : 41.461754, -74.443577

Give it a shot.  You'll see what I mean.

has anyone else experienced this problem?  any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't rely on mapquest. They have my home 1 block from it's correct location. They show my home in what is a vacant house 1 street west. Need contact info so can advise them of their error.

Answer (score 0):

I compaired it with [openstreetview](http://openstreetview.org/?lat=41.461754&lon=-74.443577&zoom=18) the result is the same as in [google maps](https://maps.google.de/maps?ll=41.461754,-74.443577&z=18). It seems that just [mapquest](http://mapq.st/14ALqUK) does not know the streets near to your position. If you scroll out the streets seems to be the same, but I live on another continent so far I don't know that environment.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look rekire... I'm stumped.  The general area is the same, but the application that I'm writing absolutely requires that the pinpointed address be accurate.